# From slow to fast, what can I expect in performance differences using comparators between different primitive types?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, bitmap, f#

I'm working on optimizing a performance critical array comparison function, [which you can read about here on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57882/locating-a-bitmap-inside-another-larger-bitmap-with-f), and I would like to know if there's performance differences between comparing different primitive or complex types in .NET/F#/C#.

I'm comparing an array of arrays of tuples with three integers. So `Tuple<int, int, int>[][]` represents the RGB (though incidentally in the BGR order) values of each pixel in the bitmap data.

So are raw bits the fastest to compare? Are ints faster than doubles or decimals or vice-versa? Is there some place where I can see good data about this topic?

Comment: Why can't you measure it yourself?

Comment: I absolutely can. But if there's standards or known practices or known metrics that I can start with, then I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel by testing all reasonable options. =)

Answer (score 5):

I do benchmarks, and this is exactly the type of question I would investigate myself by writing benchmarks.
The reasons are:

1. You have a specific question. No one can answer it exactly.
2. I've often seen 'wrong' information given.
3. Benchmarks allow you to optimize your code by comparing techniques.

That said, the data-type size should be the determining factor, natives being faster than structs, which are faster than classes.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer

Comment: I don't have enough reps to comment... And the last sentence was an answer.